# How much missing data can you replace with data imputation?

Tags: logistic, missing-data, data-imputation

I have a data set with 40 participants that underwent 20 different tests. For most of these tests all the data is there. For 2 of the 20 tests, 2 out of the 40 values are missing. However, for 5 of the tests (due to financial limitations and this test being expensive) we only about 25 participants have data. Is it possible to fill in those remaining 15 values for those 5 tests using data imputation or is that too many values missing?

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/149140/how-much-missing-data-is-too-much-multiple-imputation-mice-r?rq=1 seems relevant.